When did graduate student teaching assistants become common in universities?
Looking through the literature, there seems to be very little information available on when the modern practice of using graduate teaching assistants (GTAs) became common in university science and engineering curricula.
The one source that I could find Jennifer Meitl's 2008 MS thesis Graduate teaching assistant (GTA) development in the college classroom mentions that the widespread use of TAs was a response by universities to the sudden increase in students during the 1950s and 1960s, but does not cite any references to support that assertion.
This is such an important feature of modern higher education that it would be useful to know how it got its start. Does anyone happen to know of resources discussing this?

Can you provide a link to that thesis?

@close voters: How is this a shopping question?

Could this be related to the GI Bill?

Are you assuming a US context?

Wrzlprmft: I have added a hyperlink to the thesis PDF. @Anyon: I'm not thinking just of the U.S., but the U.S. system is the one that I am most familiar with.

I don't have an exact answer, but would bring up 3 points to consider.
First, it is not clear that the term 'teaching assistant' has held the same meaning (paid graduate student position) over the long haul - from some delving into university histories the title has also been used for, well, people hired to assist in teaching various classes. In the early 1900s many institutions did not want to hire women as 'professors', so they got the less prestigious title of 'teaching assistant' and were the first fired in case of budget issues. It is also used in primary and secondary school settings where such personnel are not graduate students. The National Center for Education Statistics (nces.ed.gov) prefers the term 'graduate assistant'.
The Google Ngram for 'teaching assistant' looks like:

Meanwhile, the Ngram for 'graduate assistant' looks like:

'Graduate assistant' seems, to me at least, more precise of a term and more likely to indicate a graduate student helping teach a class (or do research - sigh). The difference in growth rate may indicate a shifting preference in language.
Still, the large growth in 'teaching assistant' usage needs an explanation. Lets look at National Center for Education Statistics data:



Year
Enrollment




1899-1900
237,592


1909-1910
355,213


1919-1920
597,880


1929-1930
1,100,737


1939-1940
1,494,203


1949-1950
2,444,900


1959-1960
3,639,847


1969-1970
8,004,660


1979-1980
11,569,899


1989-1990
13,538,560


1999-2000
14,791,224


2009-2010
20,313,594


2020-2021
19,027,410



Since 1900, enrollment in institutions of higher learning in the United States has increased by a factor of 85. During that time the overall population increased from 76 million in 1900 to 329 million in 2020, roughly quadrupling. This means a roughly 20-fold increase in the percentage of the population attending college.
The post-war growth is quite striking, going from 1.5 million students in 1940 (before Pearl Harbor brought the US into WW2) to 2.4 million in 1950 with service veterans using the GI bill. (The GI Bill passed in 1944.) By 1960 the numbers were up to 3.6 million, with Korean veterans added under the GI bill, but college enrollment not yet affected by the post-war baby boom.
From 1960 to 1970 college enrollment more than doubled as the baby boomers came in. From 1970 to 1980 it increased by nearly 50% again. Growth slowed through 1990 and 2000, but jumped again by 2010 to over 20 million.
The post-war era also ignited significant government research funding to universities, particularly in STEM. For example, the National Science Foundation was established in 1950. This increased funding allowed an increase in graduate student populations, and this increase in turn provided a ready pool of new professors to accommodate the huge growth in enrollment.
Teaching assistants and graduate assistants have been around for 100+ years. Their number has greatly increased due to (1) a huge increase in overall enrollment, and (2) government support for university research.

Notice the big drop from about 1972 to 1980. That was the post moon-landing era (and mine - sigh).

@Buffy - indeed, there were large decreases in government funding for research (NASA, DOE, DOD, ...) that impacted graduate student funding. Quite clear in the 'graduate assistant' plot, less so in the 'teaching assistant' plot, again perhaps because 'teaching assistant' covers a range of actual positions at least some of which are not graduate assistantships.

Is ngram really a good indicator of growth for these occupations?

@Bergi - I'm open to better options. So far I have not turned up data on graduate assistant employment numbers over the last century.

For those interested, the US Bureau of Labor Statistics (https://www.bls.gov/oes/current/oes259044.htm) has current numbers for "Teaching Assistants, Postsecondary" at the link, but I can't find historical data easily.

"Graduate assistant" can also be a graduate student hired by the university for other duties, unrelated to either teaching or research.  Administrative support, athletic programs, etc.

@NateEldredge - indeed, and someone familiar with the Bureau of Labor Statistics data could pull that specific labor code data. I'm not qualified to do so, but that code seems pretty clearly more on topic.
